# Is there a way to look inside and modify an adb backup created file?

Tags: backup, adb

I created a backup of my Galaxy Nexus with `adb backup`. The resulting file is named backup.db and it's somehow encrypted.

I wanted to restore the backup, but it stops when it comes to restoring `com.android.providers.contacts`. I used `adb logcat` to find out what's going on and found out that `com.android.acore` crashes during the restore process.

I'd like to gain access to the data in the backup and remove the contacts database to restore everything back to my phone. Are there any other ways restoring the data from the backup?

Comment: I believe none of the answers without using Java will work on encrypted phones. See my answer here: android.stackexchange.com/a/224474/95893 summing up the use of nelenkov's app (github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor). Unfortunately Izzy's Adebar perl scripts ab2tar will not work on encrypted backup files.  Similar:  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28481/how-do-you-extract-an-apps-data-from-a-full-backup-made-through-adb-backup

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The file is not encrypted, unless your specify so when creating the backup. It is however compressed (using deflate). You can find out the exact format by looking at Android source (com/android/server/BackupManagerService.java) code, and, technically, should be able to extract specific data from it. However, IIRC, there are some file integrity checks in place, so it most probably won't work if you just delete a bunch of data from it. Unfortunately the `restore` command doesn't seem to have an option to restore a particular app/package only or exclude a package.

Comment: Thanks! That's at least a starting point to look inside the file. Would have been easier if I hadn't provided a password for the backup.

Comment: If you provided a password, it is indeed encrypted. `BackupManagerService' has details on the actual encryption algorithms, and key derivation paramters (salt, iteration count etc) are written in the file header. Since you know the password, you can derive the key and decrypt the data. So it's still doable, but not particularly easy...

Comment: Yes, I'm currently extracting everything from `BackupManagerService` to read the contents of the backup file. It's a good amount of work, but I need my data back...

Comment: @ingorichter I started working on this and posted a ton of notes below, in a "community wiki" answer. Feel free to add to it.

Answer (score 59):

I started working on this. I'm posting my results so far here as a "community wiki" answer for two reasons: first, if someone else wants to join in, there's a place to talk; second, if I get pulled away from this project, there'll be hints for someone else to start working.

The backup logic on the host is entirely contained within https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/commandline.cpp, in the function named `backup`. The function is *very* simple: it validates the command line options, sends the command mostly as-is to the adb daemon on the phone, and writes the phone's output to the file. There isn't even error-checking: if, for example, you refuse the backup on the phone, `adb` just writes out an empty file.

On the phone, the backup logic starts in `service_to_fd()` in https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/adb/services.cpp. The function identifies that the command from the host is `"backup"`, and passes the unparsed command to `/system/bin/bu`, which is a [trivial shell script](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/cmds/bu/bu) to launch `com.android.commands.bu.Backup` as the main-class of a new Android app process. That calls `ServiceManager.getService("backup")` to get the backup service as an `IBackupManager`, and calls `IBackupManager.fullBackup()`, passing it the still-unused file descriptor (very indirectly) connected to the `backup.ab` file on the host.

Control passes to `fullBackup()` in [com.android.server.backup.BackupManagerService](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/backup/java/com/android/server/backup/BackupManagerService.java), which pops up the GUI asking the user to confirm/reject the backup. When the user do so, `acknowledgeFullBackupOrRestore()` (same file) is called. If the user approved the request, `acknowledgeFullBackupOrRestore()` figures out if the backup is encrypted, and passes a message to `BackupHandler` (same file.) `BackupHandler` then instantiates and kicks off a `PerformAdbBackupTask` ([same file, line 4004](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/8e7057ccf3824d1421a12abad7a2ba8b07e877c6/services/backup/java/com/android/server/backup/BackupManagerService.java#L4004) as of time of writing)

**We finally start generating output there, in `PerformAdbBackupTask.run()`**, between [line 4151](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/8e7057ccf3824d1421a12abad7a2ba8b07e877c6/services/backup/java/com/android/server/backup/BackupManagerService.java#L4151) and [line 4330](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/8e7057ccf3824d1421a12abad7a2ba8b07e877c6/services/backup/java/com/android/server/backup/BackupManagerService.java#L4330).

First, `run()` writes a header, which consists of either 4 or 9 ASCII lines:

1. `"ANDROID BACKUP"`
2. the backup format version: currently `"4"`
3. either `"0"` if the backup is uncompressed or `"1"` if it is
4. the encryption method: currently either `"none"` or `"AES-256"`
5. (if encrypted), the "user password salt" encoded in hex, all caps
6. (if encrypted), the "master key checksum salt" encoded in hex, all caps
7. (if encrypted), the "number of PBKDF2 rounds used" as a decimal number: currently `"10000"`
8. (if encrypted), the "IV of the user key" encoded in hex, all caps
9. (if encrypted), the "master IV + key blob, encrypted by the user key" encoded in hex, all caps

The actual backup data follows, either as (depending on compression and encryption) `tar`, `deflate(tar)`, `encrypt(tar)`, or `encrypt(deflate(tar))`.

**TODO**: write up the code path that generates the tar output -- you can simply use tar as long as entries are in the proper order (see below).

**Tar archive format**

App data is stored under the app/ directory, starting with a _manifest file, the APK (if requested) in a/, app files in f/, databases in db/ and shared preferences in sp/. If you requested external storage backup (using the -shared option), there will also be a shared/ directory in the archive containing external storage files.

```
$ tar tvf mybackup.tar
-rw------- 1000/1000      1019 2012-06-04 16:44 apps/org.myapp/_manifest
-rw-r--r-- 1000/1000   1412208 2012-06-02 23:53 apps/org.myapp/a/org.myapp-1.apk
-rw-rw---- 10091/10091     231 2012-06-02 23:41 apps/org.myapp/f/share_history.xml
-rw-rw---- 10091/10091       0 2012-06-02 23:41 apps/org.myapp/db/myapp.db-journal
-rw-rw---- 10091/10091    5120 2012-06-02 23:41 apps/org.myapp/db/myapp.db
-rw-rw---- 10091/10091    1110 2012-06-03 01:29 apps/org.myapp/sp/org.myapp_preferences.xml
```

**Encryption details**

1. An AES 256 key is derived from the backup encryption password using 10000 rounds of PBKDF2 with a randomly generated 512 bit salt.
2. An AES 256 master key is randomly generated
3. A master key 'checksum' is generated by running the master key through 10000 rounds of PBKDF2 with a new randomly generated 512 bit salt.
4. A random backup encryption IV is generated.
5. The IV, master key, and checksum are concatenated and encrypted with the key derived in 1. The resulting blob is saved in the header as a hex string.
6. The actual backup data is encrypted with the master key and appended to end of the file.

**Sample pack/unpack code implementation** (produces/uses) tar archives: https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor

Some more details here: http://nelenkov.blogspot.com/2012/06/unpacking-android-backups.html

Perl scripts for packing/unpacking and fixing broken archives:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=27840175#post27840175

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138098/discussion-on-answer-by-jon-is-there-a-way-to-look-inside-and-modify-an-adb-back).

Answer (score 8):

Great and detailed answer from [Nikolay Elenkov](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/15494/nikolay-elenkov). However I should added that somebody already develop a software that do just that and package it here: http://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor/

The package contains both Java and Perl tool. I myself prefer Perl over Java any day, so I extracted the Perl codes, make sure they are executable, installed the required Perl library, and run the `backupdecrypt.pl` against an adb backup file, and it convert it into a tar or gzipped tar file without any issue.

I even formed a one liner in Bash 3 that allow me to do adb backup directly to gzipped tar file:

```
adb backup -f >(backupdecrypt.pl -D -z - backup.tgz) -all
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, they packaged the tool (the Java one) I wrote:) I also helped port the thing to Perl. If you didn't read the READMEs, it might not be immediately apparent that the writeup came first, then the tools....

Comment: I have taken backup but it has not created .ab file, instead it has created .backup file. I want to know how to extract it. Also i am not sure whether it has taken all the photos and video's as backup?

Answer (score -3):

For explore existing backup file, try [http://www.adb-backup.com](https://www.adb-backup.com) page, it is simple without "dd", "tar", ...

Data is not stored on this server. I've developed this online service to make it easier to view backups without manipulating with dd / tar or installing additional software. I'm author www.adb-backup.com

Comment: I'd be **very** careful about uploading an adb backup (and providing the password) to a random website... The data included in the adb backup is private and you have no way of knowing what the site does with the backup. It could be harmless but I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Comment: Data is not stored on this server. I've developed this online service to make it easier to view backups without manipulating with dd / tar or installing additional software. I'm author www.adb-backup.com