# Get data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webview.db from backup.ab

Tags: backup, webview

I followed [Nikolay Elenkov's method](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/23358/16575) of unpacking `backup.ab`.

Is it possible to get `data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webview.db` from `backup.ab`?

Comment: When I saw the title on the front page, I was going to suggest you read Nikolay's blog on the subject. His stuff is always good. He's got a book coming out too: [Android Security Internals](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1593275811).

Answer (score 1):

I found a bypass to this problem. Just do a full adb backup including all app data, apk and system data. Then root the phone and restore everything from backup. Then I would be able to access data/data/com.android.browser/databases/webview.db using Root Explorer on my phone.

Comment: To extract it in an easier way, take a look at [How do you extract an App's data from a full backup made through “adb backup”?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/16575). Multiple options available :) Your method was not mentioned there -- and brings us to one more: you could have used the Android Emulator to restore to...