# Rescue data from an application

Tags: applications, internal-storage, data-recovery

I was using [Secret of Happiness](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.soh) for about three months, and created some notes during this time period. At one point when I wanted to add a new note, the application froze, and I had to force close it.

I tried to look for the directory where it stores data. I hoped it would be some database, XML, or CSV format so I could view the notes data, but wasn't able to find it. I also tried to copy the app's data to the SD card but it's not there either.

How can I find out where this app stores its data, and how can I view my notes again?

Answer (score 0):

Each app gets a storage directoy assigned in `/data/data/<package_name>`<sup>1</sup>, so in your case that would be `/data/data/com.soh`. However, without root privileges, you cannot directly access that directory.

A possible work-around (for non-rooted devices) would be to create an "ADB backup" of the app (see our [adb tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adb/info) for details), and then "disassemble" that<sup>2</sup>. You should then find databases (SQLite) as well as "shared_prefs" (XML files) with additional information.

---

<sup>1</sup> see also: [Where in the file system are applications installed?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/3002/16575)
<sup>2</sup> see: [How do you extract an App's data from a full backup made through “adb backup”?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28481/16575), [Is there a way to look inside and modify an adb backup created file?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/23357/16575)