# Geometry Dash custom songs download location

Tags: files

I am currently using a Samsung Galaxy Xcover 3 (Model Number - SM-G388F) running KitKat 4.4.4. I would like to have some of these songs on my computer and phone, and this means that I need to find the download location.

Places that I have looked:

- `/data/data` = Empty (no folders inside the `/data` folder)
- `/sdcard/Android/data/` = No folder for the correct Geometry Dash games
- Nowhere visible on the root of the internal SD card

*I am having trouble trying to find the application data location for any of my applications*

Where do the custom songs download with custom levels in Geometry Dash get stored on the phone?

If it's relevant, the version of Geometry Dash is 2.011.

Comment: Related: [Where Android apps store data?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924/16575) And sure, `/data/data` appears to be empty unless you check it with root powers :)

Comment: Can't root the phone as it is a loan from my family. But the best I can do is use Es file explorer with hidden files, this still doesn't show any folders inside the data/data/ area

Comment: To be more specific, one I click data, no folders show, meaning that I can't go data/data/ but rather just data/ with nothing else showing

Comment: Wrong, Matt. Those contents are not "hidden" in that way (which would mean names starting with a dot, like `.hidden`), but by [OS/file-system permissions](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/file-permissions/info). Nothing ES can do about that unless your device is rooted. If `/data/data` would be really empty, that would mean your device was just factory-reset and not booted up after that :)

Comment: I figured as such, but it was worth a try To see if the music files were stored in a different directory

Comment: I would be able to adb to do this correct? Any instructions on using adb as I haven't used it much at all

Comment: Sure it was. If that were not an option, I'd written an answer instead of a comment :) I cannot verify that (not using the app), hence I only left a hint to the most likely cause. And no, ADB would also need root for that. Though you could try `adb backup`, and then investigate the resulting `.ab` file (see [Is there a way to look inside and modify an adb backup created file?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/23357/16575)).

Comment: Thanks for the info about file systems, geuss it's time to use adb

Comment: Matt, you could use a root agent and unroot when the time comes

Comment: @Dan B I will justvuse ADB and then post van answer if I find the location of the songs, but the will have to wait till tomorrow for me

Comment: Alright. Let us know how it goes. Good luck!

Comment: well in the folder sdcard/android/data there is a geometry dash folder ( if you move geometry das hon sd card ) u can try that

Comment: @Shika as my other comments state, I believe it is in the data/data/ folder, but due to the fact that I don't have root, and do not want to root my Samsung phone, I have left this task for a later date. I now own the pc version and can now easily access any download song via thatbwaybif necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need root access to find the folder.

Steps:

1. Root your phone
2. Install an application like ES File Explorer that has the root explorer function.
3. Go to `/data/data/com.robtopx.geometryjump/files`
4. Paste song, name of song must be song ID (Newgrounds)

Note: If you don't see the folders after `/data/data`, then either the file explorer doesn't support root explorer or your device is not rooted.

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer, Not sure if you read the above comments in my question, but we had come to the conclusion that it would be in the data/data/ folder (for which I would require root to access), I was relly hoping for when I asked this question that the songs would have been put into a custom location away from the data/data/ folder structure. Also as stated in the comments, I know have the steam version and as such this is no longer a problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've already got an answer, but...
You could just search the song name in Newgrounds, which is where the songs are from, and then just click the giant yellow button that says "Download this song!"
::vv

Comment: Thanks for your contribution – but what is Newgrounds, and how does it help finding a file on the local device? OP didn't ask for internet sources to download from ("download location" in the context above means the place files were downloaded to, not from).