# Where are notepad notes stored?

Tags: internal-storage

A simple question really, where do apps such as notepad store their data (the notes)?

Additionally, where do offline games store their information (such as what level you're on)?
I've looked at the android/data/ files, but they're often empty. Any tips?

Example below:

[image: According to this, the app uses 30+mb of data]
According to that, the app uses 30+ mb of data

[image: But, the file for that app (Internal Storage/Android/data/...) only has 8mb inside it. Where's the rest?]
But, the file for that app (Internal Storage/Android/data/...) only has 8mb inside it. Where's the rest?

Edit: what's a "data" file? Here's my internal storage:
[image].

I'm on EMUI 9.1.0 and Android 9.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! The data should be in `/data/data/` folder.

Comment: Can't find a data file. Updated with more info.

Answer (score 2):

Android apps follow rules where each app is stored unter `<pkgname>`
and usually the data is stored in databases. big data (games) usually stored in `obb`

`/storage/emulated/0` is your Internal Storage (which is a view for `/data/media/0`)
`/data/user/0` is a symlink to `/data/data` (where you have no access)
`/data/user_de/0` is rarely used for some apps (not sure if this my country code or stands for DeviceEncrypted)

so the example paths looks like this

```
/data/user[_de]/0/com.randomlogicgames.battletext/files/
/data/user[_de]/0/com.randomlogicgames.battletext/databases/
/data/user[_de]/0/com.randomlogicgames.battletext/shared_prefs/
/data/user[_de]/0/com.randomlogicgames.battletext/cache/
/storage/emulated/0/Android/obb/com.randomlogicgames.battletext/
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.randomlogicgames.battletext/files/
```

Comment: So how exactly do I gain access to this "data/data" file (or the other ones)?

Comment: you don't. thats actually the sense of permissions

Comment: So there's physically no way (without rooting I assume)?

Comment: you can create backup and extract it https://android.stackexchange.com/a/211956