# Unable to access internal SD card in Redmi 6 pro

Tags: internal-sd, redmi-6

I am not able to access the internal SD card of my Redmi 6 Pro mobile which runs MIUI version 11.0.5.0 and Android Version 9 PKQ1.180917.001. In settings it is showing storage 64 GB. However when I try to access the files, it is saying that /sdcard is not mounted. The "df -h" command in a terminal emulator shows that "/dev/block/dm-2" is mounted on "/data". But I am unable to access it. My applications are running smoothly except that it is unable to support any storage requirement and not able to retrieve the data already stored in the internal storage. Please note that my issue is with the internal memory and NOT the external memory card. In fact, I am also not able to access any external SD card, if provided.

Edit:  As per the suggestion by @beeshyams, I installed "Storage Isolation" app from the given link and it gave the following warning. "Incompatible storage structure detected. The storage directory of current user is /sdcard instead of /storage/emulated/0........". It seems that if I mount the sdcard to the correct location, the problem may be solved. But how to do it?

Comment: Install this app and see if you can access storage https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ianhanniballake.localstorage

Comment: @beeshyams Tried it but not able to access the storage!

Comment: I assume your device is rooted and you have changed something in the system? Because a non-working internal storage on a generally working phone is very unusual.

Comment: @Robert: The device is not rooted yet. It was not detecting an external SD card and when it asked for format SD card, I went for it. But I ma not sure whether I accidentally give permission for formatting internal SD card. But when I go to Settings->Storage, it is showing "Available: 5.00 GB Total : 64.00 GB", which is correct. But I am not able to access it. Is there a possibility that it is mounted in a different location than expected?

Comment: @beeshyams As per your suggestion, I installed "Storage Isolation" app from the given link and it gave the following warning. "Incompatible storage structure detected. The storage directory of current user is /sdcard instead of /storage/emulated/0........". How can I mount it to the correct location? I will update the question with this info.

Comment: just to clarify: your device does not have internal SD card. *'/sdcard'* is a symlink to *'/storage/emulated/0'* (which is real location *'/data/media/0'*) - therefore it is not possible to accidentally formatting internal SD card (it is only possible to format whole *'/data'* partition - factory reset)

Comment: @alecxs Thanks for the info. I was just trying to give a rough picture about what I was doing just before malfunction of my phone. The OS and other installed applications are intact, except that the internal storage space is not accessible!

Comment: i am afraid you can't fix anything without root permissions (at least, i don't know any other method than factory reset)

Comment: @alecxs Do you think that the factory reset will solve this issue? Is there any option to manually mount it by connecting to a PC and take a back up of data?

Comment: yes, factory reset will solve any problems (as long as your device is still in official state) - no, there is no solution for full backup to PC

Comment: `adb backup` will help you at least for some apps. there is a tool [Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar) and for SMS [MyPhoneExplorer](https://fjsoft.at/en) you can modify apps to allow backup https://android.stackexchange.com/q/210545

Comment: it is possible to [by-pass](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4061651) bootloader lock and install [TWRP](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3851959) from [EDL mode](https://github.com/bkerler/edl) (but this is for experts only)