# Unlocking Google Pixel 2 XL without losing data

Tags: bootloader-lock, google-pixel-2

I need to unlock my Google Pixel 2 XL without losing my data. I figured out the simple solution of doing a hard reset, but I can't lose all the important things on my phone because I need them for court and all of my clients of 20 years for work.

I can't afford to buy any software, so I downloaded an app called Dr.Fone, but unfortunately it does not support Pixel at this time. I am not the most computer or tech-informed when it comes to these things, so I went to a local phone store and ask if they have software to do this and still no luck. I also tried to follow some YouTube tutorials and did not have luck there, either due to my lack of ability to obtain some of the resources or actions that they needed me to perform from the phone because I cannot get into the system.

Is it possible to unlock Google Pixel 2 XL without losing data?

Comment: Are you able to log into the same Google account that is associated with your device, on say, a desktop or laptop computer?    If so, you can visit google.com/android/devicemanager to possibly assist in managing your device.

Comment: [adb backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/210545) would be one method of backup non-rooted device, but it requires access to device. if you [locked-out](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/locked-out/info) no tool in the world can help you, that is security per design. but every device has at least one bonded google account (otherwise you couldn't use Google Play) use [official](https://support.google.com/accounts/troubleshooter/2402620) unlock solution to set a temporary screen lock password from PC with this google account (see @CzarMatt comment)

Comment: if your data is that important consider paying for a professional [unlock service](https://multi-com.eu/,details,id_pr,21684,key,data-recovery-from-mobile-phone-or-tablet,smenu,forensic_tools.html) maybe they can [bruteforce](https://youtu.be/rTnGg0XEWPM) pin/pattern

Answer (score 4):

Android devices always delete all user data when unlocking the bootloader.

This is a requirement by Google which has to be implemented by each and every device. In the past there were a few devices that did not perform a full wipe or had other bugs, but as far as I remember Google Nexus/Pixel devices were never affected by such problems.

Therefore I would not trust any software that claims to unlock the bootloader without data loss.

The way to go is to make a backup of all data, unlock the bootloader and then restore the backup. If an app does not allow to make a backup, sometimes the app itself has an integrated backup function to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you have saved the files of your clients or any other important files on the phone (internal) storage, then copy those files to an SD card or computer. Then, reset your device, in which it will delete every app and file on the phone storage. After setting up your device from the start, move all the important files on phone storage.