# Which files does `adb backup -apk -shared -all -f <filename> back up?

Tags: adb, backup

I wanted to back up everything on my phone: call logs, messages, whatsapp texts, photos, videos, screenshots, screen video captures, recordings, app data... and everything else, before selling my phone. So, basically, data-wise, I wan't to create a clone of the (entire) current state of my phone. I don't necessarily wan't to restore all of it on my new phone, but I want to be able to access the stuff that I backed-up on my computer later, when needed...I saw a few answers on this site, but they don't answer my questions fully.

1. Is the command line `adb backup -apk -shared -all -f <filename>` well-suited to my purpose?
2. My phone has `32G` capacity, but the backup file generated is only `5.3G`. How do I know that the backup completed properly and contains all the data I wanted?
3. Are there ways to do the backup over a network (`WAN`) using `ADB`, instead of having to depend on the USB debugging mode.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fully backup non-rooted devices?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/28296/how-to-fully-backup-non-rooted-devices)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer Android app with offline data to NEW PHONE without ROOT](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/210545)

Answer (score 2):

**Answers:**

1. No,  `adb backup` will only backup the applications that has Backup option enabled.
2. It depends on which data
3. Yes, you use can connect to ADB over TCP (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp).

**Details**

- List applications that probably can be backed up:

```
adb shell 
for package in $(pm list packages -3 | cut -f2 -d":"); do
dumpsys package $package | grep "ALLOW_BACKUP" > /dev/null  && echo $package;
done
```

Probably: WhatsApp has ALLOW_BACKUP flag but cannot be backed up with ADB.

- Verify the backup:

To verify the application has been backed up successfully, you can use the [Android backup extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) tool.

- Storage backup:

```
adb pull /storage
```

- Backup SMS:

```
adb pull content query --uri content://sms
```

- Backup contacts:

```
adb shell content query --uri content://com.android.contacts/data
```

Comment: Note that adb is not encrypted or protected at all (security equivalent to telnet). Therefore using it over a WAN connection is not recommended. I would recommend to only use it within a private WPA2/3 secured Wifi network.

Comment: Note that `-shared` includes shared storage (SD card contents), so your point 1 is a bit incomplete. But you're correct: apps can opt-out of backup and thus would not be included.