# How can I find / transfer a single app's data files to a new phone? (unrooted)

Tags: data-recovery, data-transfer, app-data

I just got a new phone and I was able to have almost all my apps and data transfer over without an issue. Neither phone has root access.

But a couple apps (a game, a cocktail app) didn't transfer their data and don't have sync options.

I've looked through File Explorer but I can't seem to find an obvious folder for app data. I swear this used to be accessible but I assume it got changed around at some point.

I have dev knowledge so if I need to use adb or something I can. That said, ideally I can do this wirelessly because the old phone can't seem to be found by my computers.

1. How do I find the data files for an app?
2. Once I have the files, are there any extra steps beyond copy/paste like permissions or using adb?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer Android app with offline data to NEW PHONE without ROOT](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/210545/transfer-android-app-with-offline-data-to-new-phone-without-root)

Comment: I'll check once I'm back with my new phone. Is there really no way to just do it myself through the file system? It has to be an app or adb?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/47924 you don't have access to file system not even read access