# How to make a complete backup from rooted device to non-rooted device?

Tags: backup

I would like to get my data from an old rooted android phone, to a new android phone which can't be rooted. `adb backup` and `helium` aren't able to get all of my data from my rooted phone.

Is there a way for me to use the power of root in my rooted phone to make a backup, and then through non-root means restore the backup to the non-rooted phone?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transfer Android app with offline data to NEW PHONE without ROOT](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/210545/transfer-android-app-with-offline-data-to-new-phone-without-root)

Comment: no… unfortunately it just suggests adb backup, which i already tried

Comment: @əkaunt Unfortunately restoring app data of apps that disallow adb backup on an unrooted device is not possible.

Comment: @Robert do you think it is at least possible to set allowBackup directly on rooted phone without changing signature?

Comment: @alecxs I would assume yes as most properties from AndroidManifest.xml are cached in one or two central XML files. Unfortunately at the moment I don't remember where to find those files and their names.

Comment: @Robert I'd assume `packages.xml` being one of those. But still, not sure if the target will reject that as it gets the "no" from the APK (not from the XML it does not (yet) have).

Comment: @alecxs mtk-su failed on me… but setting allowBackup to true on the rooted device might be an option. I'm eagerly awaiting your answer

Comment: didn't find anything useful. guess it's not possible to change config on runtime https://stackoverflow.com/q/12870148

Comment: maybe it's possible to compile insecure [com.android.commands.bu](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/23608) to ignore manifest? but the more interesting is still the restoring process on the unrooted device. will restoring work for matching signature with allowBackup=false? if so, that's worth a try

Comment: unfortunately that's pointless [If someone
produces an apparent restore file with data for such an application,
it will not actually be restored onto the device](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a858cb075d0c87e2965d401656ff2d5bc16406da)

Comment: is it possible to recompile `adb` so that it doesnt check `allowBackup` and just backs up all programs regardless?

Comment: you probably didn't read the post from Nikolay Elenkov i have linked in comments. It's all written in [java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/backup/java/com/android/server/backup/BackupManagerService.java)