# Is there some way to move apps and settings from an Android phone to another?

Tags: device-migration

Is there some way to move apps and settings from an Android phone to another?

I remember I could open Google Store in a webpage in computer, and then see what apps are installed on a phone, and request an app to be installed on another phone. Is it still possible? I can't find it in Google Store webpage any more.

Thanks.

Comment: app itself actually is only apk file - can be installed from google play. settings are phone specific and can't migrate. apps data depends on app + phone model. nowadays it's common OEMs provide D2D transfer apps [1](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.pixelmigrate), [2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.easyMover),

Comment: [3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mi.global.mimover), [4](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.futuredial.asusdatatransfer), [5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oneplus.backuprestore), [6](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coloros.backuprestore), [7](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hicloud.android.clone)

Comment: Thanks. @alecxs. Does D2D transfer app require to be installed on both phones? The source phone has Android too old and can't install some of the apps. Which tool(s) can I use for the source phone being Kyocera Hydro Icon, and the destination Moto G Pure?

Comment: I am not sure if it's possible to migrate such android version gap. surely it's not a straightforward process. maybe check if "backup user data" entry exist in [recovery](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/kyocera/kyocera-c6730-hydro-icon/recovery-mode) mode. otherwise you could root the device, or dump userdata from [EDL](https://github.com/bkerler/edl) mode. next you could try my [script](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3775129) and see what's happen if restored to new device. another approach could be [adb backup](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/210545) or google drive