# Backup Pixel 3 before erasing phone with TWRP

Tags: twrp, fastboot, bootloader, google-pixel-3

I am attempting to take a recovery/backup of a Pixel 3 using TWRP.  I do not need to flash TWRP, just boot from it to perform the backup.  Meaning, I don't care if TWRP is installed permanently.

The problem I am running into is that I need to unlock the bootloader before I can boot TWRP.  And if I unlock the bootloader, the data on the device will be erased.

**My question is:** If I unlock the bootloader, will I be able to boot back into fastboot mode, and thus boot into TWRP, before the erasure occurs?  And if to, how do I perform this? (I presume that if I hold the volume down button it will before rebooting it will go back into fastboot mode.)

*I am trying to obtain a backup of the phone before the erase script is activated.*

I have searched around and have not been able to resolve this question as of yet.

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FBE encryption bootloader state in keys](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232224/fbe-encryption-bootloader-state-in-keys)

Comment: Not quite, but in part yes. Thank you @alecxs

Comment: in other words, even if you could unlock without erasing userdata, still it's impossible to decrypt because of bootloader state is involved in encryption

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there some way to move apps and settings from an Android phone to another?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246300/is-there-some-way-to-move-apps-and-settings-from-an-android-phone-to-another)

Comment: Thanks @alecxs, appreciated.  Really what I am trying to do is get a full nandroid backup of the phone.  If erasure is unavoidable, I'll go with that.  But I am trying to first get the nandroid backup *before* erasure occurs.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be the answer to my question:

Pixel 3 (blueline) immediately wipes the data partition upon unlocking the bootloader.  It appears there is no way to boot it back into fastboot before erasure occurs.