# Is it possible to switch to a new phone with all data?

Tags: backup, device-migration

How do I switch to a new phone transferring all data (without root access)?

All data means (at most):

- Files and folders (including some hidden files, like browser's cookies)
- Apps and their data
- Settings and app permissions

Comment: Not possible ......

Comment: @beeshyams, Is there any chance that any cell phone company (including Google) will add this feature?

Comment: I have heard of some Chinese OEMs having this feature but also that they discontinued it.  It's very unlikely that it will be added, given that Google backup service is felt sufficient (for me it's crappy)

Comment: @beeshyams, please answer this question with the most complete data switch method (not all data, but most)

Comment: OEMs provide D2D transfer apps [comment329712](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246300/is-there-some-way-to-move-apps-and-settings-from-an-android-phone-to-another#comment329712_246300)

Comment: @alecxs, but non-system apps don't have enough access to most of the data I mentioned, right?