# ADB backup with empty password

Tags: adb, backup

I have a non-rooted Android 12 device and I am trying to execute a procedure it used to work. I basically used to backup an application DB using the following commands:

- Connect phone and grant permission from it
- Create a folder and cd on it
- `adb backup -noapk com.myapp.blabla`
- *Do not input any password*
- `dd if="backup.ab" bs=1 skip=24 > compressed-data`
- `printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00"| cat - compressed-data | gunzip -c > result.tar`
- `tar xf lresult.tar`

Now for some unknown reason, it looks like I have to type a password if I want to go through. In fact, there are two buttons: "do not back up" and "back up my data". The second one gets available only if you type some letter.

I have googled a lot, but it looks like nobody had this problem.

My version is:

```
adb --version
Android Debug Bridge
version 1.0.39 Version 1:8.1.0+r23-5ubuntu2
Installed as /usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

Comment: maybe enforced from android 12? set password and use java

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to look inside and modify an adb backup created file?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/23357/is-there-a-way-to-look-inside-and-modify-an-adb-backup-created-file)

Comment: Instead of manually fiddling with the backup (that exists in 5 different versions with optional compression and encryption) I would recommend to use [Android Backup Extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor) tool to convert (`unpack`) it to a tar file.

Comment: thank you for the suggestions guys, I'm going to try them

Comment: Ok, i've seen the links. I already saw it in the past, but I had problems in making it work. The only way I succeeded is in fact the method I have told you about. The only problem is the fact that now it requires a password.. no idea why or how to circumvent this

Comment: Unfortunately we can't help if password is enforced. `abe.jar` works fine with password

Comment: what do you mean that the password is enforced?

Comment: on other android devices one can leave password blank. not sure that is some change in android 12 or just something special by your OEM

Comment: I've understood.. thank you all for your replies